# Eigenvalue and Eigenvector of special matrices

Tags: matrices

Find atleast one eigenvalue and eigenvector of the following matrices:

(i) a $N \times N$ unit matrix ( a matrix with all entries as $1$)

(ii) a $N \times N$ matrix obtained by deducting an identity matrix from unit matrix ( a matrix with all $0$ diagonal entries and all $1$ non diagonal entries).

Are there some special properties of these matrices and any context in which they are useful?

Comment: I did see a pattern in the eigenvalues.But I have no idea about the theory behind it.

Comment: Try to explain us your observations.

Comment: I understood the answer given below.I will try induction and let you know if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Every column of the unit matrix is $(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ and every entry of the matrix is equal, so what happens if you add up all columns of the matrix? And what vector multiplication is that equivalent to? Also, if you subtract the identity matrix from a matrix then the eigenvectors are the same and the eigenvalues are $\lambda - 1$ where $\lambda$ was the eigenvalue of the original matrix for the eigenvector. This is fairly easy to show.

Comment: Thanks.I got it. Does it have any significance in any real world application?

Comment: There are many examples of special kinds of matrices where the easiest way is to "reason" about the matrix to prove in general what are the eigenvectors and eigenvalues are, rather than compute them from the basic $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$. Often tricks are involved. This is a fairly easy example where you can use some tricks. If you want a further challenge for this problem using "tricks", try to figure out what the eigenvectors are for eigenvalue $0$.